# Loading scenes from a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have project for iPad, which perfectly working on Xcode 4.X, but when I updated Xcode to 5.0 something was going wrong.

If I do not go into the details, I  have 2 scenes. By clicking on Image in Quiz Scene, app loading Big Picture Scene. By clicking on screen in Big Picture Scene, app returning to Quiz Scene.

[image]

In new Xcode when I returning to Quiz Scene from Big Picture Scene, all actions not working (for example, i cant go to Big Picture again. Clicking on Image - not going to Big Picture, but NSLog showing that app trying to load Big Picture Scene)

QuizViewController.m :

```
-(IBAction)showBigPicture:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoBigPicture" sender:self];

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqual:@"gotoBigPicture"])

    {
        ELBigPictureSceneViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.currentQuestion = _currentQuestion;
        vc.currentPackage = _currentPackage;
    }
}
```

BigPictureViewController.m :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

   NSLog(@"big picture viewWillAppear");
   NSLog(@"%@",_currentQuestion.image_uri);

    NSString *imageNameJPG = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[_currentQuestion image_uri]];

    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNameJPG];

    [super viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated];
}

- (IBAction)gotoQuiz:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backToQuiz" sender:self];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqual:@"backToQuiz"])
    {
        ELQuizViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.currentQuestion = _currentQuestion;
        vc.currentPackage = _currentPackage;
    }
}
```

NSLog showing correct value of "_currentQuestion.image_uri", but scene not loading second time. Also, this project working fine in older Xcode.

Comment: It's always a good practice to add `[super viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated]` in the `viewWillAppear`. Not that I has anything to do with this.

Comment: `NSLog` shown the correct value both time?

Comment: Thank you for answer! Trying to add "[super viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated]", but still not working correct. (Question edited)
NSLog showing correct value all the time

Comment: How about the `_imageView`, is it nil the second time?

Comment: Not empty.
Adding NSLog(@"%@",_imageView); after "_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNameJPG];"



first time: `2013-09-22 17:23:28.557 quizapp[4253:a0b] <UIImageView: 0xa3910e0; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa3796e0>>`

second time: `2013-09-22 17:23:34.561 quizapp[4253:a0b] <UIImageView: 0xa39ebc0; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa3786f0>>`